# Formatting filepaths using variables on in os.path

Tags: python, opencv, filepath, os.path

I've written a script that splits a video file into frames using cv2 and some other modules. Up to now, I was happy pasting in the filepaths and running the code, but now I want the user to input the filepaths and names in response to a prompt. This should be easy, but I'm having a lot of trouble making os.path work for me. The main problem is that I want the name of each image file (i.e. frame) to have a number in it that shows where it comes in the sequence. The code below is what I have:

```
filepath = input('Please enter the filepath for the clip: ') 

clip = cv2.VideoCapture(filepath)

#### This code splits the clip into scenes

filepath1 = input('Please enter the filepath for where the frames should be saved: ') 

name = input('Please enter the name of the clip: ') 

ret, frame = clip.read()
count = 0
ret == True
while ret:
    ret, frame = clip.read()
    cv2.imwrite((os.path.join(filepath1,name, '(%d)','.png') % count, frame))
    count += 1
```

However, the produces the following error:

```
cv2.imwrite((os.path.join(filepath1,name, '(%d)','.png') % count, frame))
    TypeError: Required argument 'img' (pos 2) not found
```

Including the `% count, frame` variables in the parentheses in the os.path.join command gives a different error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What it should do is write a number of .png files called `name(x)` to a location like `MYcomputer/mydesktop/myfolder/`. I'm not sure what's gone wrong here––any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parenthesis placement as well as the usage of `join` is wrong This

```
cv2.imwrite((os.path.join(filepath1,name, '(%d)','.png') % count, frame))
```

should be corrected to this:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(filepath1, name+'(%d).png'%count), frame)
```

To further improve the code I would suggest

```
fname = "{name}({count}).png".format(name=name, count=count)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(filepath1, fname), frame)
```

Here a brief explanation of `os.path.join`: It concatenates all the arguments with the path delimiter of your OS ("/" on Unix-Based and "\" on Windows). As the result, your original code would result in following string:

```
filepath1 = "some_dir"
name = "some_name"
count = 10
print(os.path.join(filepath1, name, '(%d)' % count,'.png'))
>>> "some_dir/some_name/10/.png"
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this much up for me! However, I'm now getting a different error:

`cv2.imwrite((os.path.join(filepath1,name+'(%d).png'%count), frame))
TypeError: Required argument 'img' (pos 2) not found`

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: As I said, check your "(" and ")" placement ;) imwrite needs as 1st argument the filepath, and then the image. you pass a tuple with the filepath and the image. So the double-"(" and -")" are too much.

Comment: Ah yes, I see <coughs embarrassedly>. Thanks a million, for the fix and the education! Works fine now